# Unknown option -RequireConsent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

Everything worked fine before I branched my trunk, now this error list shows up in the branch and the trunk. Google search brought up a possible solution in the Nuget blog, which has different error messages than I do.

[image]

Comment: Shows up where? When youj build, when you get latest/commit? Also, is it a message box or output to a console or log?

Comment: When I try to build. I included an image of the error list that Visual Studio produces. The only solution I could find in a practical amount of time was to remap to a new folder and get latest.

Comment: Verify your workspace and it's permissions. Only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asked Jeff Handley via twitter, he responded "nuget.exe update -self"

Works!  Strange thing is that it was a complete refresh install of Windows 7 with a new copy of VS2010.  And somehow I have Nuget 1.7.  Ah well...

```
C:\Tfs\Products\Development\Project1\.nuget>nuget.exe update -self

Checking for updates from https://nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 1.7.30402.9028.
Updating NuGet.exe to 2.0.40000.
Update successful.
```

Comment: I'm going to branch again soon and I'll try this if I get the error again. Thanks.

Comment: The nuget.exe within the .nuget folder is put in place when you Enable NuGet Package Restore.  However, so is the nuget.targets file.  Somehow, your nuget.targets file got updated, but your nuget.exe did not.  We recently changed the targets/exe to use a -RequireConsent flag so that nuget.exe only requires consent to download data when the flag is present.

Comment: Seems like when I got latest from TFS, it probably brought the 1.7 targets up.  However, the "update -self" command might be a good idea to do even at the end of NuGet v2 installs. The odd thing is that I had NuGet 2.0 installed before repaving my computer and encountering this.